# Is the expression "topping it the ______" really used anywhere?

Tags: phrases, idioms, expressions

I've often read books where English men made statements about others "topping it the knob" or "topping it the gentleman," which I took to mean over playing a role or attitude.

Is this a legitimately used idiom, or is it archaic, or even possibly fabricated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't recognise this idiomatic usage, but there are a dozen or so instances of [top/topping it the knob/nob](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22topping%20it%20the%20gentleman%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&gs_nf=1&tok=evSKHFjlc7ooMnIUCbCWzg&ds=bo&pq=%22top%20it%20the%20nob%22&cp=13&gs_id=4g&xhr=t&q=%22top%20it%20the%20knob%22&pf=p&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&oq=%22top%20it%20the%20knob%22&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=490946d29378b2b8&biw=1466&bih=886) in Google Books - so in a limited sense, the expression does exist. But that link is typical for all verb forms and spellings - they're mostly novelist [Patrick O’Brian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_O%27Brian), from 15 years ago or less.

I suspect this use of *to top [it the something]* relates to OED's sense 15:

> Theatr. to top one's part, to play one's part to its utmost possibilities or to perfection; to transcend the character assigned to one; transf. to sustain (a character) with success. *to top the officer (Naut.)*

Thus, *"to **top** [it] the xxx"* can be seen as being related to:

> ["Don't **come** the high and mighty"](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=18840&p=44045)
>
> ["He's always **playing** the fool"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/play+the+fool)
>
> ["I'll just **act** the innocent"](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/to%20act%20the%20innocent)

---

I also suspect "knob" is *always* incorrect here, since I'm pretty sure the *nob* being referenced is [noun - Chiefly British Slang. *a person of wealth or social importance*.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nob) Since I find no evidence of *"top **it** the [noun]"* being used earlier than a couple of decades ago, I doubt it's "archaic". It's either a (deliberately or accidentally) garbled version of *"top the [noun]"*, or an obscure dialectal usage.

Comment: I think you're spot on about *nob*. But I note that most of the references at Google Books are from several Patrick O'Brien novels in the Jack Aubrey series, using both spellings; two others are from works on nautical subjects; and your OED citation ends with a nautical reference. Another GB  reference is to a work about the early history of New Zealand. Is it perhaps a seaman's phrase O'Brien ran across in his studies of the Napoleonic era?

Comment: @StoneyB: I noticed that O'Brien accounted for a lot of the (tiny) total, but didn't dig too deep. I found [top the officer](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22you+are+to+top+the+officer%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) back in 1847, but O'Brien 1998 seems to be first with his *nob/knob* - I now think he bungled his pseudo-archaism, frankly.

Comment: Perhaps he just made it up to see how far it would go.

Answer (score 1):

I’m also familiar with the phrase from the Aubrey/Maturin series. It is apparently used as a pejorative reference about someone “topping the nob “ by putting on airs, acting above one’s station, a common person acting like a “nob” or nobility.